# Android jni not use singleton mode

Tags: android, java-native-interface, singleton

I have a class named `FJpegStreamReader`, that has loaded a jni (.so):

```
System.loadLibrary("fjpeg");
```

and has a singleton constructor:

```
 private static volatile FJpegStreamReader mInstances;
    public static FJpegStreamReader getInstance() {
        if (mInstances == null) {
            synchronized (FJpegStreamReader.class) {
                if (mInstances == null) {
                    mInstances = new FJpegStreamReader();
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstances;
    }
```

when i invoke it with singleton, it work well,

```
FJpegStreamReader.getInstance().open("/sdcard/markers.jpg", FJpeg.MODEL_OPEN);
```

But now, i dont want to use singleton mode,  I try to change `FJpegStreamReader`   , and invoke like this :

```
FJpegStreamReader readerA = new FJpegStreamReader();
FJpegStreamReader readerB = new FJpegStreamReader();
readerA.open("/sdcard/markers1.jpg", FJpeg.MODEL_OPEN);
readerB.open("/sdcard/markers2.jpg", FJpeg.MODEL_OPEN);
Bitmap bmA = readerA.getBackgroundImage();
Bitmap bmB = readerB.getBackgroundImage();
```

and readerA work well, but readerB goes error.  i want it can be instanced more than one time in the same time,  how to make that readerA and readerB all work?

```
25884-25884 I: JNI_OnLoad Called
25884-25884 I: FilePath: /sdcard/markers1.jpg, and OpenMode: 0
25884-25884 I: offset is：15079
25884-25884 I: Start to Parser Data
25884-25884 I: Open Succeed
25884-25884 I: FilePath: /sdcard/markers2.jpg, and OpenMode: 0
25884-25884 E: Fired to Open File(code: -1001)
```

This is my `c++` method:

```
unique_ptr<FJpeg> f(new FJpeg);

static jboolean
FJpeg_open(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring fileName, jint model) {
    const char *c_path = NULL;
    c_path = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileName, NULL);
    LOG_I("FilePath: %s, and OpenMode: %d", c_path, model);
    int rel = f->openFile(c_path, model);
    if (rel < 0) {
        LOG_E("Fired to Open File(code: %d)", rel);
        return false;
    }
    LOG_I("Open Succeed");
    return true;
}

...

int FJpeg::openFile() {
    if (file_path == NULL || *file_path == '\0' || (open_mode != 0 && open_mode != 1)) return ERROR_CODE_UNSUPPORTED_OPERAND;
    if (open_mode == 0) {
        f_in.open(file_path, ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (f_in.fail()) return ERROR_CODE_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
        return checkOffsetAndEnd();
    } else {
        f_out.open(file_path, ios::out | ios::binary);
        if (f_out.fail()) return ERROR_CODE_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but readerB goes error"_ **What** error?

Comment: I have updated the question. I just use ifstream.open() in my c++

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'singleton constructor', and there isn't one here either.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne  I made a singleton to FjpegStreamReader's constructor, to make sure there always one instance in the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all your Java FJpegStreamReader objects share a single c++ FJpeg object.

You will need to change that to associate each Java object with a unique FJpeg object, for example bystoring either the raw address in a long field in the Java class, or a handle to it and converting both back to a pointer in your Jni methods.

Comment: I guess so, but what should i do?  Who's raw addr should be stored in java class? and How to convert?

Comment: The address of a `FJpeg` object, that you cast from/to `jlong` stored in a `long` field in your object.